# How do i delete the contents of an install dir after my chef run is successful?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have a /u01/installs dir and want to only delete the contents if the chef run completed successfully. In case of errors, i want to preserve the directory for debugging. 
I would prefer a cleanup recipe but not sure how to check for a successful check run.

PS: I am using chef solo.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `directory` resource with `action :delete` and `recursive true`. You'll need to be very careful about idempotence if you do this, but an error will abort the converge so it will never get to that resource.

Comment: Thanks for the response @coderanger. What do i do if i want to preserve the directory but delete the contents. I plan to create a cleanup recipe and put a bash/execute resource in it to clear the contents ?

Comment: Chef does not have anything for that.